# About tensorflow 2.3.0-rc1

Tags: tensorflow, version

I recently updated my tensorflow version to 2.3.0. When I output the version, I found it was 2.3.0-rcl. I want to know what the latter ‘rcl’ means. Thank you.

Comment: It means release candidate 1, you installed a beta version of tensorflow, not the final version.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> It means release candidate 1, you installed a beta version of
> tensorflow, not the final version (paraphrased from Dr. Snoopy)

To install latest version, you can try as shown below

```
pip install tensorflow #install TF 2.5.0
```

For specific version, you can try as shown below

```
pip install tensorflow==2.3.0  # install TF 2.3.0
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)